# tensorflow installation for python audacity assignments on OS-X

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to work through the tensor flow iPython assignments for the deep learning Udacity course. I'm doing this on my brand new Macbook Pro and I am totally new to Mac.

I'm using anaconda python 2.7 and I followed the pip tensor flow installation instructions from the tensorflow website and all seemed to be well. However the tensorflow import statement tells me the module does not exist.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This usually happens, when `pip` does not belong to anaconda (you are using the wrong pip, there will be multiple!). But unless you provide the exact commands you used we can only speculate.

Comment: Did you [install tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#download-and-setup)?

Comment: Ah ... I sudo-reinstalled pip and went through the tensor flow installation procedure again and now it seems to work. Thanks for the hint :-)